# how to omit duplicates in pyparsing?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

Ok, I finally got my grammar to capture all my test cases, but I have a duplicate (case 3) and a false positive (case 6, "PATTERN 5"). Here are my [test cases](http://nielsolson.us/pastebin/TestCases.txt) and my [desired output](http://nielsolson.us/pastebin/DesiredOutput.txt).

I'm still pretty new to python (though able to teach my kids! scary!) so I'm sure there are obvious ways to solve this problem, I'm not even sure this is a pyparsing issue. Here's what my output looks like for now:

```
['01/01/01','S01-12345','20/111-22-1001',['GLEASON', ['5', '+', '4'], '=', '9']]
['02/02/02','S02-1234','20/111-22-1002',['GLEASON', 'SCORE', ':', ['3', '+', '3'], '=', '6']]
['03/02/03','S03-1234','31/111-22-1003',['GLEASON', 'GRADE', ['4', '+', '3'], '=', '7']]
['03/02/03','S03-1234','31/111-22-1003',['GLEASON', 'SCORE', ':', '7', '=', ['4', '+', '3']]]
['04/17/04','S04-123','30/111-22-1004',['GLEASON', 'SCORE', ':', ['3', '+', '4', '-', '7']]]
['05/28/05','S05-1234','20/111-22-1005',['GLEASON', 'SCORE', '7', '[', ['3', '+', '4'], ']']]
['06/18/06','S06-10686','20/111-22-1006',['GLEASON', ['4', '+', '3']]]
['06/18/06','S06-10686','20/111-22-1006',['GLEASON', 'PATTERN', '5']]
['07/22/07','S07-2749','20/111-22-1007',['GLEASON', 'SCORE', '6', '(', ['3', '+', '3'], ')']]
```

Here's the grammar

```
num = Word(nums)
arith_expr = operatorPrecedence(num,
    [
    (oneOf('-'), 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
    (oneOf('* /'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    (oneOf('+ -'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ])
accessionDate = Combine(num + "/" + num + "/" + num)("accDate")
accessionNumber = Combine("S" + num + "-" + num)("accNum")
patMedicalRecordNum = Combine(num + "/" + num + "-" + num + "-" + num)("patientNum")
score = (Optional(oneOf('( [')) +
         arith_expr('lhs') +
         Optional(oneOf(') ]')) +
         Optional(oneOf('= -')) +
         Optional(oneOf('( [')) +
         Optional(arith_expr('rhs')) +
         Optional(oneOf(') ]')))
gleason = Group("GLEASON" + Optional("SCORE") + Optional("GRADE") + Optional("PATTERN") + Optional(":") + score)
patientData = Group(accessionDate + accessionNumber + patMedicalRecordNum)
partMatch = patientData("patientData") | gleason("gleason")
```

and the output function.

```
lastPatientData = None 
for match in partMatch.searchString(TEXT):
    if match.patientData:
        lastPatientData = match
    elif match.gleason:
        if lastPatientData is None:
            print "bad!" 
            continue 
       # getParts() 
        FOUT.write( "['{0.accDate}','{0.accNum}','{0.patientNum}',{1}]\n".format(lastPatientData.patientData, match.gleason))
```

As you can see, the output isn't as good as it looks, I'm just writing to a file and faking some of the syntax. I have been struggling with how to get ahold of the pyparsing intermediate results so I can work with them. Should I just write this out and run a second script that finds the duplicates?

Update, based on Paul McGuire's answer. The output of this function gets me down to one row per entry, but now I'm losing pieces of the score (each Gleason score, intellectually, has the form `primary + secondary = total`. This is headed for a database, so pri, sec, tot are separate posgresql columns, or, for the output of the parser, comma-separated values)

```
accumPatientData = None
for match in partMatch.searchString(TEXT):
    if match.patientData:
        if accumPatientData is not None:
             #this is a new patient data, print out the accumulated
             #Gleason scores for the previous one
             writeOut(accumPatientData)
        accumPatientData = (match.patientData, [])
    elif match.gleason:
        accumPatientData[1].append(match.gleason)
if accumPatientData is not None:
    writeOut(accumPatientData)
```

So now the output looks like this

```
01/01/01,S01-12345,20/111-22-1001,9
02/02/02,S02-1234,20/111-22-1002,6
03/02/03,S03-1234,31/111-22-1003,7,4+3
04/17/04,S04-123,30/111-22-1004,
05/28/05,S05-1234,20/111-22-1005,3+4
06/18/06,S06-10686,20/111-22-1006,,
07/22/07,S07-2749,20/111-22-1007,3+3
```

I would like to reach back in there and grab some of those lost elements, rearrange them, find the ones that are missing, and put them all back in. Something like this pseudocode:

```
def diceGleason(glrhs,gllhs)
    if glrhs.len() == 0:
        pri = gllhs[0]
        sec = gllhs[2]
        tot = pri + sec
        return [pri, sec, tot]
    elif glrhs.len() == 1:
        pri = gllhs[0]
        sec = gllhs[2]
        tot = glrhs
        return [pri, sec, tot]
    else:
        pri = glrhs[0]
        sec = glrhs[2]
        tot = gllhs
        return [pri, sec, tot]
```

Update 2: Ok, Paul is awesome, but I'm dumb. Having tried exactly what he said, I have tried a few ways to acquire pri, sec, and tot but I'm failing. I keep getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stage1.py", line 81, in <module>
    writeOut(accumPatientData)
  File "Stage1.py", line 47, in writeOut
    FOUT.write( "{0.accDate},{0.accNum},{0.patientNum},{1.pri},{1.sec},{1.tot}\n".format( pd, gleaso
nList))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'pri'
```

These AttributeErrors are what I keep getting. Clearly I don't understand what's going on between (Paul, I have the book, I swear it's open in front of me, and I don't understand). Here's [my script](http://nielsolson.us/pastebin/Stage1.py). Is something in the wrong place? Am I calling the results wrong?

Comment: The link to the "desired output" file seems to be broken.

Comment: I don't see what you do if multiple Gleason scores are defined for a single patient data. Do you just take the first one? The last one? Or are they redundant and it doesn't matter which one you take?

Comment: Regarding multiple gleason scores: for now, I'm assuming the first complete score (p+s=t) is correct. Any other complete scores should mean the same thing and any other occurrence of "gleason" is likely referring to a tertiary pattern or obscure reference I don't care about.

Comment: This is the problem now. In `writeout`, you are passing `gleasonList` as the 1th argument to `format`, but lists don't have a "pri" attribute. `gleasonList` is not a parsed Gleason score, it is a list of parsed Gleason scores. Just to get things working, replace `gleasonList` with `gleasonList[0]` in your call to `format` - I'm pretty sure that will take care of things. Then the only cleanup you need to do is to actually walk the list of gleason scores, and pick the *best* one (by your criteria, the one that is most complete), not just the first one.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Question: is there anything like http://pythontutor.com for the desktop, so I could see the running process and step through what's happening? (pythontutor.com unfortunately doesn't support modules and doesn't support more than 300 steps)

Comment: I've used winpdb to step through my running Python scripts. Don't be put off by the "win" part, it works on Linux too.

Comment: Sweet! I will definitely be playing with that this weekend! Thanks again, Paul. Hopefully next time you hear from me meaningful progress has been made!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't make a single change to your parser, but made a few changes to your post-parsing code.

You are not really getting "duplicates", the issue is that you print out the current patient data every time you see a Gleason score, and some of your patient data records include multiple Gleason score entries. If I understand what you are trying to do, here is the pseudo-code I would follow:

```
accumulator = None
foreach match in (patientDataExpr | gleasonScoreExpr).searchString(source):

    if it's a patientDataExpr:
        if accumulator is not None:
            # we are starting a new patient data record, print out the previous one
            print out accumulated data
        initialize new accumulator with current match and empty list for gleason data

    else if it's a gleasonScoreExpr:
        add this expression into the current accumulator

# done with the for loop, do one last printout of the accumulated data
if accumulator is not None:
    print out accumulated data
```

This converts to Python pretty easily:

```
def printOut(patientDataTuple):
    pd,gleasonList = patientDataTuple
    print( "['{0.accDate}','{0.accNum}','{0.patientNum}',{1}]".format(
        pd, ','.join(''.join(gl.rhs) for gl in gleasonList)))

accumPatientData = None
for match in partMatch.searchString(TEXT):
    if match.patientData:
        if accumPatientData is not None:
            # this is a new patient data, print out the accumulated 
            # Gleason scores for the previous one
            printOut(accumPatientData)

        # start accumulating for a new patient data entry
        accumPatientData = (match.patientData, [])

    elif match.gleason:
        accumPatientData[1].append(match.gleason)
    #~ print match.dump()

if accumPatientData is not None:
    printOut(accumPatientData)
```

I don't think I'm dumping out the Gleason data correctly, but you can tune it from here, I think.

EDIT:

You can attach `diceGleason` as a parse action to `gleason` and get this behavior:

```
def diceGleasonParseAction(tokens):
    def diceGleason(glrhs,gllhs):
        if len(glrhs) == 0:
            pri = gllhs[0]
            sec = gllhs[2]
            #~ tot = pri + sec
            tot = str(int(pri)+int(sec))
            return [pri, sec, tot]
        elif len(glrhs) == 1:
            pri = gllhs[0]
            sec = gllhs[2]
            tot = glrhs
            return [pri, sec, tot]
        else:
            pri = glrhs[0]
            sec = glrhs[2]
            tot = gllhs
            return [pri, sec, tot]

    pri,sec,tot = diceGleason(tokens.gleason.rhs, tokens.gleason.lhs)

    # assign results names for later use
    tokens.gleason['pri'] = pri
    tokens.gleason['sec'] = sec
    tokens.gleason['tot'] = tot

gleason.setParseAction(diceGleasonParseAction)
```

You just had one typo where you summed `pri` and `sec` to get `tot`, but these are all strings, so you were adding '3' and '4' and getting '34' - converting to ints to do the addition was all that was needed. Otherwise, I kept `diceGleason` verbatim internal to `diceGleasonParseAction`, to isolate your logic for inferring `pri`, `sec`, and `tot` from the mechanics of embellishing the parsed tokens with new results names. Since the parse action does not return anything new, the tokens are updated in-place, and then carried along to be used later in your output method.

Comment: Paul, thank you, again. You've probably spent more time teaching me than it would have taken you to do it, so I'm doubly appreciative. I tuned it a bit but I'm still loosing pieces of the scores. ==A== I think I'm stuck with lists instead of tuples: if you read the test cases, case 6 implies 4 + 3 = 7 and then says there's a tertiary (not usually reported) score of 5. So the 7 is never explicitly stated, which means that tuple would be short an element. ==B== I still can't rearrange the ones where the primary and secondary scores appear on the right hand side.

Comment: I marked this as accepted, though I hope you're willing to take a look at my last sticking point: I keep getting attribute errors. Files are at http://nielsolson.us/pastebin/